# Download PDF in local and upload a PDF to sql db in a single button click event

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a PDF downloaded in the button click event .I want to upload the same PDF in the same event.
File is getting downloaded with out any issues .But after Response.end no code is getting executed to upload the file to SQL db.

Please suggest in VB.net

TIA

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & fileName)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfContent)
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Close()
    'HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
```

Answer (score 0):

CompleteRequest can be used instead of End as that might help to execute code after end

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest?view=netframework-4.8